# Unable to calculate authorization code for aws s3 using java code?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, authorization

I am trying to calculate the aws authorization code using java code but that is not working giving error:

```
String host = "bucketname" + ".s3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com";
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
        long expireTime = cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;

        String signString = "GET\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            expireTime + "\n" +
            "/" + "testingsagar" + "location";

        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(SECRET_KEY.getBytes(), HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHM);
        mac.init(signingKey);
        String signature = URLEncoder.encode(new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(mac.doFinal(signString.getBytes()))));

        System.out.println(signature);
        String fullPayload = "?AWSAccessKeyId=" + ACCESS_KEY +
            "&Expires=" + expireTime + 
            "&Signature=" + signature;

        System.out.println("http" + "://" + host + "" + fullPayload);
```

Can anyone please suggest me java code which I can use to calculate the authorization code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The string to sign is actually missing a couple of elements, like the region for example (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_elements.html)

See Java code sample here 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-java

The AWS SDK for Java has a Signer component that implements this for you - no need to write your own code
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWS4Signer.html

Comment: Sorry, I can not code for you, but see Java code sample here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-java